# Rate of change of norm of a quaternion

Tags: linear-transformations, rotations, quaternions

I am new to quaternions and currently trying to learn it. Here is my doubt. Let $\bf{q}$ be a quaternion whose norm is defined as $\|\bf{q}\| = \sqrt{q\otimes q^*}$. As you see, this norm is a scalar quantity. We'ld expect that the rate of change of this scalar quantity is also scalar (or, am I wrong in assuming that). The rate of change of this norm is computed as:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{d}{dt}\|\bf{q}\| &= \frac{d}{dt}\left(\bf{q}\otimes \bf{q}^*\right)^{1/2}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\|\bf{q}\|}\left(\dot{\bf{q}}\otimes \bf{q}^* + \bf{q}\otimes \dot{\bf{q}^*}\right)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
We see that the denominator is a scalar quantity, but since $\bf{q}$ is vector, the numerator is also vector, resulting into the rate of change of a scalar quantity being vector. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This is a good example where too flamboyant notation just obfuscates what is going on. Hint: write $\|\mathbf{q}\|$ as $\sqrt{q_0^2+q_1^2+q_2^2+q_3^2}$ and restart the calculation.

Comment: I understand that using $\|\bf{q}\|$ = $\sqrt{q_0^2+ q_1^2 + q_3^2 + q_4^2}$ simplifies the understanding. But why do I get different answer if I use the definition of norm as given by one of the relations in  equation (27) of https://www.iri.upc.edu/people/jsola/JoanSola/objectes/notes/kinematics.pdf

Comment: The point is that this ugly thing $(\bf{q}\otimes \bf{q}^*)^{1/2}$ is the same as $\sqrt{q_0^2+ q_1^2 + q_3^2 + q_4^2}$ and there is *no way* that the time derivative of that scalar is a vector. If that pdf claims something else either scrap it or transcribe something in mathJax into your question.

Comment: BTW: the symbol $\otimes$ is usually reserved for the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of two matrices. This is a scalar only if the two matrices are $(1\times 1)\,.$

Comment: @Kurt G. This symbol is "polysemic" (it is also used for direct sums of subspaces, etc. ) : it is not absurd to use it for quaternion products because it reminds of the connection of quaternion product with cross product.

Comment: The document has been cited more than 500 times and so there will be some truth in the equations. We can assume that they are abusing the notation for quaternion multiplication. But what I wanted to know is if there is anything wrong with the time derivative that I have used?

Comment: You did a correct calculation. Hint: $\dot{\mathbf{q}}\otimes\mathbf{q}^*$ and its brother are not vectors :) .

Comment: If we use en (210) from the document in place of $\dot{\bf{q}}$, we get $\dot{\bf{q}}\otimes \bf{q}^*$ $ = \frac{1}{2}\bf{q}\otimes\boldsymbol\omega\otimes\bf{q}^*$ which is rotation of $\boldsymbol\omega$ by angle $\bf{q}$, which makes it vector. See equation (114)

Comment: The context you gave so far in OP shows that the time derivative of $\|\mathbf{q}\|$ is a scalar as it should. Please do not try to make me read a pdf that has 210+ equations. Write a self contained question that follows the standards of MSE.

Comment: @JeanMarie You are right that there is a connection of quaternion multiplication and [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Quaternions). Nonetheless: that $\mathbf{q}\otimes\mathbf{p}$ stuff is clumsy and imho better used for Kronecker. Regarding [direct sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum) of sub spaces. Never seen $\otimes\,.$ Only $\oplus\,.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment and correction to one of my comments.

The author of the paper you cited in the comments uses $\mathbf{p}\otimes\mathbf{q}$
to denote the quaternion product. He writes each quaternion as
$$\mathbf{q}=\begin{bmatrix}q_w\\\mathbf{q}_v\end{bmatrix}\,,\;q_w\in\mathbb R\,\,,\;\mathbf{q}_v\in\mathbb{R}^3\,.$$
Then

> $$\tag{13}\mathbf{p}\otimes\mathbf{q}=\begin{bmatrix}p_wq_w-\mathbf{p}_v^\top\mathbf{q}_v\\[2mm]
> p_w\mathbf{q}_v+q_w\mathbf{p}_v+\mathbf{p}_v\times\mathbf{q}_v\end{bmatrix}\,.$$

The complex conjugate of a quaternion $\mathbf{q}$ flips the sign of its
imaginary part $\mathbf{q}_v\,.$
Since $(-\mathbf{p}_v)\times(-\mathbf{q}_v)=\mathbf{p}_v\times\mathbf{q}_v=-\mathbf{q}_v\times\mathbf{p}_v$ we get from (13)

$$\tag{1}
(\mathbf{p}\otimes\mathbf{q})^*=\mathbf{q}^*\otimes\mathbf{p}^*\,.
$$
Differentiation of $\mathbf{q}\otimes\mathbf{q}$ gives the sum of

\begin{align}\tag{2}
\dot{\mathbf{q}}\otimes\mathbf{q}^*\quad\text{ and }\quad\mathbf{q}\otimes\dot{\mathbf{q}}^*
\end{align}
which are both quaternions having possible non zero imaginary parts. In other words: in your language they are vectors in general.

From (1)
$$
(\dot{\mathbf{q}}\otimes\mathbf{q}^*)^*=\mathbf{q}\otimes \dot{\mathbf{q}}^*\,.
$$
That is: the "vectors" in (2) are conjugate to each other.
Therefore their sum is the sum of their scalar parts and hence a scalar as it must.

Comment: I will accept this answer with a minor change that you need to make : $\left(\dot{\mathbf{q}} \otimes \mathbf{q}^*\right)^* = \mathbf{q} \otimes \dot{\mathbf{q}}^*$.

Comment: How nice of you, Mr. Journal Referee :) Just making that minor change would have been unfair to our readers. I hope the "paper" did not become to long and is still acceptable.